# Calculating $\Gamma (n+5/2)$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Hey I'm pretty new to the gamma function and was trying to calculate $\Gamma (n+\frac52)$.
I got to the integer $\int_0^\infty t^{n+\frac32}e^{-t}\mathrm dt\\$, and I really don't know how to go on from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ is equal to?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt\pi$ right?

Answer (score 1):

There is the easy way of using the identity $z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$.

However, we will use the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula)
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{\Gamma(z)}.
\end{align}

In particular, when $z = n+\frac{5}{2}$ we see that
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(n+2+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 2^{-2n-4}\sqrt{\pi} \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align}

Comment: Ohh, that makes very much sense, thanks alot, really aprecciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt\pi$$
$$\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})=\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})\frac{3}{2}=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\ \frac{1}{2}\ \frac{3}{2}$$
Following this pattern:
$$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\ \frac{1}{2}\ \frac{3}{2}...\frac{2n-1}{2}=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n-1)}{2^n}$$
$$1\cdot3\cdot5...(2n-1)=\frac{2n!}{2\cdot4\cdot...2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$
Therefore
$$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}=\sqrt\pi\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}$$
I know it is not rigorous, but the result is proper ;).